# select data by curl from influxDB

Tags: influxdb

I try to select data from influxdb on my raspberry. I don't know what's wrong.
Here is my curl command:

```
pi@rpi:~ $ curl -i -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=ELT_2 -u admin&p=admin' --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM "msg.masurement"'
400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious your command is wrong.
Write the command as:

```
curl -i -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=ELT_2&u=admin&p=admin' --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM "msg.masurement"'
```

Even after correcting that, if you still get the error then maybe masurement spelling is wrong.